# Method to determine if difference is statistically significant

Tags: statistics

I have a dataset of 133 points for which I have an expected value of an event $X$ occurring $68.12$ times.

I just ran the dataset and $X$ ended up occurring $84$ times. I am pretty sure my expected value is wrong and something statistically significant is going on here but I want to run a statistical test of some sort to prove it.

Is there any test I can run for statistical significance in this case without standard deviation?

Comment: Can't you estimate the standard deviation and use a t-test? But it's unclear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Seems to me a t-test has nothing to do with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

With some reading between the lines, it seems to me your null hypothesis is
that binomial success probability is $p = 68.12/133 = 0.5122.$
Now you have observed $X = 84$ and wonder if it came from 
$\mathsf{Binom}(n=133,p=0.5122).$ Your estimated success probability
is $\hat p = 84/133 =  0.6316$ (which does seem a lot larger than $0.5122).$

Then it seems you want to test $H_0: p = .5122$ against $H_1: p \ne .5122.$
If that is the case, the hypothetical standard error $SD(\hat p)$ is
$\sigma_{\hat p} = \sqrt{p(1-p)/n} = .0433.$

Using a normal approximation to binomial for your test, you have
$$Z = \frac{\hat p - .5122}{.0433} = \frac{.6116 - .5122}{.0433}= 2.91.$$ Because $|Z| > 1.96,$
you reject $H_0$ at the 5% level of significance. So it seems your
hunch that you have the wrong success probability was correct.

*Another approach* is to note that if $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(133, .5122),$
then $P(X \ge 84) = 0.00365.$ So the P-value for a one-sided test is 0.00356.
Double that for a two-sided test. Either way, the P-value is much less than
5%, so you conclude the true success probability isn't .5122.

```
1 - pbinom(83, 133, .5122)
[1] 0.003654153
```